# PHP multibyte safe preg_replace Vs. str_replace

Tags: php, regex, escaping

Good day!

I am having some troubles with `preg_replace` and utf-8 characters. The following code-fragment:

```
$v = "line1\nline2\r\nмы хотели бы поблагодарить";
print $v;
print preg_replace("#\R#", "", $v);
print preg_replace("\n", "", $v);
```

returns the following output:

```
line1
line2
мы хотели бы поблагодарить

line1line2мы �отели бы поблагодарить

line1line2
мы хотели бы поблагодарить Вас
```

For some reason the х is unreadable when `\R` is used but it is unaffected when `\n` is used. As `\R` is PHP specific I suppose this generates the problem. Does anybody have a clue about how I could use `\R` (which is not accepted by `str_replace`) in `preg_replace`? I fear this problem might be happening in many other cases, not only with capital chi.

Comment: have you tried function like utf8decode or encode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a Unicode input, you must pass `/u` flag to the regex to deal with the input correctly:

```
$v = "line1\nline2\r\nмы хотели бы поблагодарить";
echo preg_replace('/\R/u', "", $v);
// => line1line2мы хотели бы поблагодарить
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/PaqPPI)

This `/u` flag is required when both pattern and input can contain Unicode string literals.